# Trying to install an app with node-sass on WSL. Getting "gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2"

Tags: magento, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node-gyp, node-sass

I was trying to install some magento storefront app that requires linux to run on WSL. I managed to get most things working, but in the end I'm stuck at trying to install the dependencies. When it tries to install node-sass, I get this error:

```
    make: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Github/psp-storefront-magento2/node_modules/node-sass/build'
make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/mnt/c/Github/psp-storefront-magento2/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
gyp ERR! command "/home/lursmani/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node" "/mnt/c/Github/psp-storefront-magento2/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Github/psp-storefront-magento2/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.10.0
```

I read that deleting yarn.lock and installing again should fix this, but it hasn't helped in my case. Would greatly appreciate some help with this, if anyone knows what's funky here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently GYP has issues with the latest version of Node (16). I had to downgrade to Node 14 and then it worked correctly.

Comment: I struggled to install a `node-gyp` related package for 3 days. After I switched to Node 14, everything worked! Thank you!